# Using postfix/suffix operator in an assignment

Tags: c

Is it acceptable to have a post/prefix operator on the lhs of an assignment operator?

```
#include<ctype.h>
void to_upper_in_place(char* string)
{
    while(*string++ = toupper(*string));
}
```

If it is OK, is the previous considered readable C code, or should it be turned into something like the following?

```
#include<ctype.h>
void to_upper_in_place(char* string)
{
    while(*string) {
        *string = toupper(*string);
        string++;
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
while(*string = toupper(*string++));
```

Comment: In many circumstances, it is absolutely readable, IMO.  This is precisely the sort of thing that `++` and `--` are for.  But you have to be careful when LHS and RHS use the same pointer, as they do here.

Comment: @SteveSummit ok, thanks, is it considered better practice to put the post-increment on the lhs or rhs then? Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: Having such an operator on the LHS is okay in itself, but when the same variable appears elsewhere in the expression, you have UB in many cases (including yours).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior?rq=1

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you have to *ask* if it is readable answer the question of if it is readable or not?

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon.  Comment edited.  If you have the same pointer `string` on both sides, the answer changes quite a bit.

Comment: *Is it acceptable to have a post/prefix operator on the LHS of an assignment operator?* yes, in general it is valid, however if you do that on the LHS then you can only use that variable on the LHS, using it anywhere else in the same assignment is undefined behavior.

Comment: `for (int c; (c=*string) != 0; *string++ = toupper(c));` might be preferable.

Comment: To avoid UB when `*string < 0`, use `unsigned char* string`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- I see. What would be an example of when it would be `< 0` though?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 `char` is either _signed_ or _unsigned_.  When `char` is signed, it can have a value like -2, yet `toupper()` is only defined  when `EOF` or for values in the `unsigned char` range.  In general, C library treats characters as if they were `unsigned char`.  So too should your code.

Comment: Like `void to_upper_in_place(char* string) { unsigned char *s = string;  while(*s = toupper(*s)) { s++} }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at several different cases.

(1)
(with two *different* pointers)

```
*dest++ = toupper(*src++);
```

This is perfectly ordinary C style.

(2)

```
*dest = toupper(*src);
src++;
dest++;
```

This is "longhand" style.  You might write it if you were scared of using `++` in a dangerous way.  (And a certain amount of caution is indeed justified, as we're about to see.)

(3)
(back to the same pointer on lhs and rhs)

```
*p = toupper(*p);
p++;
```

This is fine.

(4)

```
*p++ = toupper(*p);
```

This is problematic, because `p` is both used and modified in the same expression, with the modification not depending on the value used.  In many/most cases, this pattern renders the expression *undefined*, and that's a Bad Thing.  It ends up being particularly hard to say wheteher this particular case is actually undefined, but for that reason we have to stay on the safe side, and say that (3) is preferable.  (For more -- *much* more -- on this kind of undefined behavior, see [this beleaguered old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior).)

(5)

```
*p = toupper(*p++);
```

This is even worse.  It's equally potentially undefined, but if it works at all, it probably increments `p` too soon.

(6)
Yet another arrangement is to put the increment into the loop header, by using a `for` loop instead:

```
for(; *p; p++)
    *p = toupper(*p);
```

This is also fine.

Comment: NIce answer - love the _Bad Thing_ part.